# Flutter log spams

Tags: android, flutter

I couldn't find a way with Flutter 1.15.17 and Android Studio 3.6.1 to hide lots of logs .

```
D/InputEventReceiver( 9585): dispatchInputEvent - MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=527.6743, y[0]=1281.5549, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=86214164, downTime=86214164, deviceId=6, source=0x1002 }
V/View    ( 9585): onTouchEvent io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{749998f VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,1776}
I/PhoneWindow( 9585): cb.dispatchTouchEvent handled
D/InputEventReceiver( 9585): finishInputEvent - MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=527.6743, y[0]=1281.5549, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=86214164, downTime=86214164, deviceId=6, source=0x1002 }
```

Does someone knows how to do it ? There's no option in Settings > Flutter.